# Django Doesn't Send Email Notifications

Tags: python, django, email

Working on a contact form and i am not able to receive the emails from Django into my Inbox.

This is my function:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
            contact_phone = form.cleaned_data['contact_phone']
            contact_period = form.cleaned_data['contact_period']
            subject = contact_name + " | " + contact_phone + " | " + contact_period

            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            contact_email = form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
            try:
                send_mail(subject,content,contact_email, ['office@cohen.ro'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "contact.html", {'form': form})

def success(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

These are my server's settings:

```
Secure SSL/TLS Settings (Recommended)
Username:   office@cohen.ro
Password:   Use the email account’s password.
Incoming Server:    mail.cohen.ro
IMAP Port: 993 POP3 Port: 995
Outgoing Server:    mail.cohen.ro
SMTP Port: 465
```

This is what i have in my Django settings:
LATEREDIT: I have commented the console and have now this line of code, but doesnt submit the email.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

#EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'office@cohen.ro'
EMAIL_HOST= 'mail.cohen.ro'
EMAIL_HOST_USER= 'office@cohen.ro'
EMAIl_HOST_PASSWORD='mypass'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

In my server i can see the message, but does not send the email to my email address so i dont know if someone is asking me something. Thank you!

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: me | 0787877 | 12-13
From: test@test.com
To: office@cohen.ro
Date: Mon, 25 Dec 2017 11:29:39 -0000
Message-ID: <151420137937.1642.9393637578495359678@My-MacBook-Air.local>

me
```

The error i got:

```
SMTPServerDisconnected at /contact/
Connection unexpectedly closed
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: SMTPServerDisconnected
Exception Value:    
Connection unexpectedly closed
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py in getreply, line 393
Python Executable:  /Users/cohen/PycharmProjects/chn/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/cohen/PycharmProjects/chn',
 '/Users/cohen/PycharmProjects/chn',
 '/Users/cohen/PycharmProjects/static_in_env',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/cohen/PycharmProjects/chn/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/Users/cohen/PycharmProjects/chn/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg',
 '/Users/cohen/PycharmProjects/chn/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg',
 '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Mon, 25 Dec 2017 13:49:16 +0200
```

Any help, would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if it a copy-paste modification mistake, but `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` contains a lowercase `L` in the word  email: `EMAIl`

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue was due to the fact that TLS was true and needed to be False ----`EMAIL_USE_TLS = False`

Now is submitting emails.